# HTML grid layout disrupted by SVG child element

Tags: html, css, svg, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a page with a simple `3x3` grid layout: header top, footer bottom, two sidebars, and the main display. Everything works fine until I add the SVG element that should fill the main-display div:

```
<div class="main">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500"></svg>
</div>
```

The whole grid layout gets confused at this point, with the browser eliminating the header, extending the page below the `height: 100%` that I have declared, etc.

I can easily "fix" this by setting my SVG `max-height` and `max-width` arbitrarily small (below ~60% in Firefox 62.0.3; in Safari 12.0, <90%). But that isn't really a fix since it leaves a conspicuous gap (a huge one in Firefox). I much prefer to size my SVG `100%` to fill its space in the grid. I must be missing something. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Adding a screenshot of what I want and (one version of) what I have.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp8C8.png) is what I have. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mdNO.png) is what I want.

The stylesheet for what you see is below. The only difference between the two images is the change in `max-width` and `max-height` from `10%` to `100%`.

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      display: grid;
      border-style: solid; // to show that body renders improperly
      border-color: red;
      grid-template-columns: 3fr 9fr 2fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 10fr 1fr;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    div {
      border: solid black 1px; // to show div positions
    }

    .header {
      grid-column: 1 / 4;
      grid-row: 1;
    }

    .main {
      grid-column: 2;
      grid-row: 2;
    }

    .side1 {
      grid-column: 1;
      grid-row: 2;
    }

    .side2 {
      grid-column: 3;
      grid-row: 2;
    }

    .footer {
      grid-column: 1 / 4;
      grid-row: 3;
    }

    svg {
      max-height: 100%; 
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="side1">Site 1</div>
  <div class="main">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500"></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="side2">Site 2</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you share screenshot what problem you are facing

Comment: do you just need preserveAspectRatio="none" on your svg element?

Comment: @RobertLongson that does not work, unfortunately; nor do other preserveAspectRatio values.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] then

Comment: @RobertLongson the code in Gerard's answer below actually illustrates my problem, but I updated my post to include some minimal HTML. I don't know what else would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is not with the svg element at all, but with its containing div (`.main` in the question's code snippet). Like flex items, grid items have a default `min-width: auto` and `min-height: auto`. By setting them to `0`, the svg is able to size automatically, as it should.

I still don't quite understand why the svg disrupted the layout, especially when it was set to `80%` in Firefox, leaving conspicuous space around it, but the problem with the grid layout itself is clear enough.

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 3fr 9fr 2fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 10fr 1fr;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    div {
      border: solid black 1px; // to show div positions
    }

    .header {
      grid-column: 1 / 4;
      grid-row: 1;
    }

    .main {
      grid-column: 2;
      grid-row: 2;
      min-width: 0;
      min-height: 0;
    }

    .side1 {
      grid-column: 1;
      grid-row: 2;
    }

    .side2 {
      grid-column: 3;
      grid-row: 2;
    }

    .footer {
      grid-column: 1 / 4;
      grid-row: 3;
    }

    svg {
      max-height: 100%; 
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="side1">Site 1</div>
  <div class="main">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500"></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="side2">Site 2</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

Comment: odd. i am having a similar problem but this does not fix the issue for me.  strangely, i didn't see the issue until i tested my code out on a desktop browser, i.e. in a mobile browser (or mobile mode in a desktop browser) it renders just fine!

Comment: Wow! I just lost half my day trying to figure this out. So weird. I found an ancient FF bug that sounds similar, where a parent width isn't calculated correctly when a child's width is set using percentage. Surely unrelated (overflow also played a role in the bug), but just illustrates the possibility of a rendering miscalculation in the browser. At any rate, thank you for saving the other half of my day!  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=829958

Answer (score 0):

Please see below. No issues encountered.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 9fr 2fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "side1 main side2" "footer footer footer";
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: thin solid black;
  /* For visibility only */
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.side1 {
  grid-area: side1;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
}

.side2 {
  grid-area: side2;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="side1">Site 1</div>
  <div class="main"><svg viewBox="0 0 500 500"></svg></div>
  <div class="side2">Site 2</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I apologize for suggesting that your code illustrated my problem. It does not, for the simple reason that it does not specify heights for the grid. If you look at my original post, I updated it with a code snippet that should illustrate more concretely the problem I faced. I did, however, find a solution. Thanks for your help!